# Does a vector over the field of meromorphic functions describe a manifold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, meromorphic-functions

Assume that the variables $\mathbf x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ are coordinates on the solution manifold of a differential equation $\mathbf D(\mathbf x,\dot{\mathbf x},\ldots,\mathbf x^{(\alpha)})=\mathbf 0$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb N$.
Let's say I have a vector $\mathbf p$ whose elements belong to the field of meromorphic functions in the variables $\{x_i^{(j)}\mid i=1,\ldots,n,j\geq 0\}$. Does $\mathbf p=\mathbf 0$ itself describe a manifold? If not, under what circumstances does it describe a manifold?

Comment: What is $\alpha$? \\ Probably you want at least some conditions to rule out trivial counterexamples like $\mathbf p(\mathbf x) = x_1 x_2$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is just some natural number (updated in question). Some condition would be interesting

Comment: I am not even quite sure I understand why $p(\mathbf x)=x_1x_2$ should be a trivial counterexample here. Can you explain that?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422825/does-a-vector-over-the-field-of-meromorphic-functions-describe-a-manifold#comment1086602_422825), because $\{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 x_2 = 0\}$ is not a manifold.